# MVC3 URL.Action not rendering my image in img tag

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-3, filecontentresult

I have an image in my view, as:

```
    <img width="150" height="150" scr="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Item")" />
```

My controller, ItemController, has this method:

```
    public FileContentResult GetImage(){
        var model = _itemService.GetItemImage(1);
        if(model != null && model.ImageData != null){
            return File(model.ImageData, model.ImageMimeType);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

When the view renders, I get the following markup for my image but no image is rendered:

```
    <img width="150" height="150" scr="/MyApp/ItemManagement/GetImage"/>
```

If I type this url 'http://localhost/MyApp/ItemManagement/GetImage' in the browser, I get the image.  I'm not sure what's wrong with this. Could someone point out what is wrong with my code please?

Thanks in advance.
Jeff

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Image attribute should be `src`...?

Comment: Thanks Charlino. I knew it had to be something simple. It was even highlighted in my view as incorrect and I missed it.

Comment: We all make little mistakes like that all the time :-)