# how do I display an image stored inside a variable in an MVC3 Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a project in which I need to display thumbnails of image stored locally on the server. At first I tried using a jquery library to just "thumbify" the original images for my view. However, later I realized serving potentially thousands of images this way will really take up the bandwidth. So below is a method that extracts windows thumbnails instead (and only one full time image will be served on demand).

The problem is though, the thumbnail is now inside a variable in a model. I don't know how actually display the image inside a Razor View. So how do I display a System.Drawing.Icon item in a view?

```
public static System.Drawing.Icon GetThumbnailImages(string imageFilePath) 
        {
            ShellFile shellFile = ShellFile.FromFilePath(imageFilePath);
            Bitmap shellThumb = shellFile.Thumbnail.ExtraLargeBitmap;
            System.Drawing.Icon shellThumb2 = shellFile.Thumbnail.Icon;
            //var shellThumb3 = shellFile.Thumbnail.MediumIcon;
            return shellThumb2;

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would count the images and generate the  tag in a loop which has an action as its source

```
for(int i= 0; i< MyModel.ImageCount(); i++){

     <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Home")" />


}
```

Your action will need to send a file back. See this as an example [Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234733/mvc3-url-action-not-rendering-my-image-in-img-tag)

This will load in the image

Comment: Thank you, I used the link, converted by icon to byte[] and used the URL.Action as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to create a new file with the new dimensions and then show it by url.
you could use something like:

```
public static string GenerateThumbnail(string filename, string target, int width)
{
    var img = Image.FromFile(filename);

    if (img.Width > width)
    {
        var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, GetTargetHeight(img.Width, width, img.Height));
        var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, width, GetTargetHeight(img.Width, width, img.Height));
        g.Dispose();

        using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite(target))
        {
            CopyStream(bitmap.ToStream(ImageFormat.Jpeg), target);
        }

        return target;
    }

    return filename;
}

private static int GetTargetHeight(int originalWidth, int targetWidth, int originalHeight)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(decimal.Round((decimal)targetWidth / originalWidth * originalHeight, 0));
}
```

and then use

```
<img src="@GenerateThumbnail("path", "targetFile", 100)" />
```

Comment: lante, I already have a thumbnail that I am pulling out of windows with windows API. Thank you for ur answer though.